# iOS - addSubview without overlap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

In a for loop, I'm trying to add Labels to a ScrollView based on a number given by the user. Here is the code in Objective-C:

```
NSInteger numberOfViews = [self.textfieldNumViews.text intValue];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews ; i++){
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 12)];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.scrollviewViewContainer addSubview:label];
}
```

The problem is that the labels are overlapping each other inside the ScrollView, when I really want them to just display one after the other.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PY1d.png) I understand that this is due to how addSubview behaves, placing views on top of other views, but is there any way I can prevent that? Or some other function I could use? I feel like this should be an easy task but I can't seem to figure it out. Is there something like a vertical layout property I can add to the ScrollView? Or add margins to the labels?

Comment: You need to provide appropriate `x` and `y` values to `CGRectMake`. Don't just hardcode `0, 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the y lower for each subview. Check the third line:

```
NSInteger numberOfViews = [self.textfieldNumViews.text intValue];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews ; i++){
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, (i*20), 300, 12];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.scrollviewViewContainer addSubview:label];
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! 

But is this the only way? For my current purposes it's an easy task, but in the future when I'm adding things to a ScrollView dynamically, it seems like I'll need to find the sum of heights for every existing child view, along with all the spacing.

Comment: No, it's probably not even the best way. You need to learn about setting layout constraints, and use those to layout your views. That's a big topic, good luck!

Comment: I especially prefer using `constraintsWithVisualFormat`.